# How can I know if my android app was built in release or debug mode?

Tags: android, release-mode, debug-mode

In my app I use Google Analytics and Admob as you know (or not) I can use both of them in a mode that doesn't influences the data on the server (debug mode).

I tired of changing each time I release my app this things and I can also mistake and release it with debug mode and then I won't get data...

How can I know programmatically if I run in debug\release mode?

In C# I can check this using:

```
#If DEBUG then
```

How can I do this in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by checking the flag

`BuildConfig.DEBUG`

And this is how I use normally.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onCreate called");
}
```

Comment: Can I use something like this in xml file?